# Как узнать что поток закончил своё выполнение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Привет всем любителям питона! Такой вопрос: как узнать что поток закончил своё выполнение?

```
def proc():
    for i in range(1000000):
        pass
p1 = threading.Thread(target=proc)
p1.start()
p1.join()
```

Comment: @kff код уже содержит [`p1.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Метод join() для потока отрабатывает только после того, как поток завершился.

   Соответственно, тот код, который должен быть выполнен после завершения потока, вы можете просто поместить после строки с join().
2. Метод isAlive() для потока возвращает True, если поток в данный момент выполняется, в противном случае - False.

   Соответственно, если p1.isAlive() вернул False, то поток p1 либо ещё не был запущен, либо уже завершился.